# php explode() not working properly with special characters

Tags: php, escaping, special-characters, explode

```
$this->row['contents'] = strip_tags($this->row['contents']);
$this->words = explode(" ", $this->row['contents']);
```

The code above should create an array with a `key => value` pair for each word of `$this->row['contents']`. Under normal circumstances it works just fine, but with a string such as:

> This costs U$ 10.40 per liter.

It will separate as

```
[0] => This
[1] => Costs U$
[2] => 10.40 per
[3] => liter.
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: This worked fine for me.... `$var = 'This costs U$ 10.40 per liter.'; echo var_export(explode(' ', $var), TRUE);`

Comment: Hexdump the string and find out if any of your supposed spaces are actually tabs or newlines, or non-breaking spaces.

Comment: Does PHP let you explode by regex? If so, explode on `\s`?

Comment: @Patashu Not with the regular explode function, you may be able to with one of the regex functions.

Comment: @mario you were right, one was a tab and the other was a newline.

Comment: with regular expression `/\s+/` , you can split white space ( like tab , space )

Answer (score 1):

maybe this code help you

```
$this->words = preg_split('/\s+/', $this->row['contents']);
```